# Egyptian fraction with least possible sum

Tags: elementary-number-theory, optimization, computational-mathematics, egyptian-fractions

Suppose that $~a~$ and $~b~$ are coprime positive integers. Then there exists representation of $~\frac{a}{b}~$ as egyptian fraction:
$$~\frac{a}{b} = \frac{1}{d_1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{d_s} ~$$

There are many algorithms for constructing egyptian fraction of whic i know greedy algorithm mentioned in Wikipedia. Unfortunately it doesn't satisfy my needs. I'm searching for two algorithms which can construct representation with

a) shortest length

b) least sum of denominators

Any ideas will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you require that $d_k$ be distinct (i.e. there is no repetitions)?

Comment: In any case see this page http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/numth/egypt/intro.html

Comment: See also this excellent paper http://kevingong.com/Math/EgyptianFractions.pdf